# Kaltura referenceid Error

Tags: kaltura

Is it possible into Kaltura referenceId length <2, while I am passing referenceId length <2 its showing error like this

> "KalturaMediaEntry::referenceId" must have a min length of 2
>   characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`referenceId` is limited to 2 characters.

See:

- For insert: https://github.com/kaltura/server/blob/Naos-14.3.0/api_v3/lib/types/entry/KalturaBaseEntry.php#L541
- For update: https://github.com/kaltura/server/blob/Naos-14.3.0/api_v3/lib/types/entry/KalturaBaseEntry.php#L696

You can append a constant character to your Reference Ids (like `_`) when you insert or update and remove it when you need to do the look up in your own system.